# Zipping a file and sending it without saving the zipped file in the process

Tags: java, udp, compression, gzip

I want to open a specific file and zip it and send the byte array of the zipped result over UDP.

Now I checked the java zip API but it only give me to save the zipped file to the computer and opening it again and send it would be inefficiency.

Is there any way to do what I need without writing an implementation of the compression algorithm of my own ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cand wrap your `ZipOutputStream` around a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and get the bytes out of the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.
Something like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
//write the entries
zos.close();
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: what do you mean by "write the entries"?,i don't want to write the result to a file

Comment: I meant to write the content of the zip file, in your case the content of the file you want to zip will be an entry.

Comment: If all that's required is that a single file be compressed for network transmission, perhaps a `DeflaterOutputStream` would be better.

Comment: but if i write an entry wouldn't it write the zipped file to a file?